# List of results from async operations

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, guava

My goal is to obtain a list of results from 10 (or some other arbitrary number) of asynchronous operations.

I'm using `com.google.guava` for the utilities in concurrency and if someone could graciously point me in the right direction I would be much appreciative.

In the example I'm trying to get a list of `successfulBombs` (`Bomb` being pretty much an empty object but has a random probability of throwing a Problem when created to simulate problems with service call execution)

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
List<ListenableFuture<Bomb>> bombs;
ListenableFuture<List<Bomb>> successfulBombs;
```

Edit:

This is what I've come up with so far but the list is empty even though it should have some successful elements... I can't quite discern why

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
List<ListenableFuture<Bomb>> bombs = new ArrayList<ListenableFuture<Bomb>>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ListenableFuture<Bomb> bomb = service.submit(new Callable<Bomb>(){
        public Bomb call() throws Problem
        {
            return craftBomb();
        }
    });
}
ListenableFuture<List<Bomb>> successfulBombs = Futures.successfulAsList(bombs);
Futures.addCallback(successfulBombs, new FutureCallback<List<Bomb>>(){
    public void onSuccess(List<Bomb> bombs)
    {
        System.out.println("My successful bombs");
        for(Bomb b : bombs)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
    public void onFailure(Throwable thrown)
    {
        System.err.println("There was a problem making this bomb.");
    }
});
```

In closing what I'm looking for:

- Correct pattern for starting asynchronous operations
- Collecting a List for the resulting operations
- Collecting a List of successful operations using the guava Framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [`ListeningExecutorService.invokeAll(List<Callable<T>>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)?  Perhaps combined with [`Futures.allAsList(List<ListenableFuture<T>>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29)?

Comment: I think you might be on to something, let me give it a shot. I was looking at `successfulAsList()` http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: `Futures.successfulAsList()` is better in your case, because some bombs might throw an exception. With `Futures.allAsList()`, one failed future will cause the `ListenableFuture<List<Bomb>>` to fail.

Answer (score 6):

The list is empty because you're never adding anything to `bombs`. You're passing an empty list to `Futures.successfulAsList`.

Comment: That did it! `bombs.add(bomb)`

Answer (score 1):

The working solution was as follows

```
    ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    List<ListenableFuture<Bomb>> bombs = new ArrayList<ListenableFuture<Bomb>>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        ListenableFuture<Bomb> bomb = service.submit(new Callable<Bomb>(){
            public Bomb call() throws Problem
            {
                return craftBomb();
            }
        });
        bombs.add(bomb);
    }
    ListenableFuture<List<Bomb>> successfulBombs = Futures.successfulAsList(bombs);
    Futures.addCallback(successfulBombs, new FutureCallback<List<Bomb>>(){
        public void onSuccess(List<Bomb> bombs)
        {
            System.out.println("My successful bombs");
            for(Bomb b : bombs)
            {
                System.out.println(b);
            }
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown)
        {
            System.err.println("There was a problem making this bomb.");
        }
    });
```